# How can I user lightgallery with Angular 7 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, lightgallery

I have added its script to `angular.json` file.

```
"scripts": ["./src/assets/js/lightgallery.js"]
```

and its styles to `style.scss` file

```
@import "./assets/externals/lightgallery.css";
```

and in my component I have tried that:

```
declare var lightGallery: any;

ngOnInit() {
   lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));
}
```

and its giving the error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: lightGallery is not defined

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `angular-lightgallery`? You can install it with `npm i angular-lightgallery`. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-lightgallery

Comment: Yes I have installed it already

Answer (score 0):

Retry the following:

1. Add `lightgallery.js` file to **assets** folder
2. Add the file path to the scripts array of the `angular.json`

   "scripts": [
       "../src/assets/js/lightgallery.min.js"
   ]
3. Import `lightgallery.css` file in the `style.scss` file

   `@import "~lightgallery.js/dist/css/lightgallery.css";`
4. Add this line of code on top of the component `.ts` file

   `declare var lightGallery: any;`
5. Use it as below:

   `lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));`